# Is there any simple quantum model by Gerard 't Hooft which can explain the double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, models, determinism

This question is directed to Prof. 't Hooft and anybody who is familiar with his papers. It is a reaction to Prof. 't Hooft's question why nobody is excited about his classical models for quantum mechnanics.
My reasoning behind the question is simple. Humans have no good intution for quantum mechanics. But they normally have a very good intution for any kind of classical model. 
Now one of the simplest and in fact the canonical example for quantum weirdness is the double slit experiment. Combining these two things I think it is a very natural question to ask.

Comment: Seems you may be interested in a debate. I suggest editing your post to follow the "FAQ":

Comment: Particularly "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: Hi Mikael, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! As Argus said, we prefer to have focused questions on this site. I think the reason your post is receiving a negative reaction is that it's hard to tell what you're really asking. If you could clarify the question, for example by identifying what simple model you want to know about, it might be better received. Feel free to ask for help improving your post using the "add comment" link just below this.

Comment: You can ask the following: what is a specific 'tHooft model which reproduces a single particle going through two slits. This is almost ok, except for the slits are hard to model since they are large numbers of things. An easier question is to reproduce the Stern-Gerlach experiment, which is more reasonable. I don't think this is so bad to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will follow your advice and rename the question. It is really about the 't Hooft models I want to ask.

Comment: Mikael, your question is a recipe for extra trouble but it is also a very good question (the question *is* in the title) and the silence when it comes to the answers is telling. Of course that the answer is No, there ain't such a model, but what's even more important is that it has become fashionable to ignore such problems, ignore the double slit experiment, ignore any genuine physics question in favor of preserving scientifically indefensible ideology. The goal of such systems of papers isn't to explain the double slit experiment or any real effect; it's to defend wrong philosophical cliches

Comment: In the meantime this question is answered satisfactorily, you can see the next related [post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/40882/solving-the-schrodinger-equation-for-the-double-slit-experiment/46153#46153), and these useful [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerard_%27t_Hooft#References).

Comment: Professor [Gerard t'hooft](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11205/g-t-hooft) happens to be a user of physics stack exchange. I wonder if there is any way to directly communicate with other members (through chat?)